# Phase shift of ricker wavelet

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing, wavelet

I have been struggling with **phase shift of Ricker wavelet**

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 100
a = 10
vec2 = signal.ricker(x, a)
print(len(vec2))

plt.plot(vec2)
plt.show()
```

I can't find how to do it through `signal.ricker` function, so I recreated the original wavelet.

```
x1 = np.arange(-50,50,1)
wavelet = []
a = 10
A = 2/(sqrt(3*a)*(pi**0.25))

for i in x1:
    i = A * (1 - (i/a)**2) * exp(-0.5*(i/a)**2)
    wavelet.append(i)
plt.plot(wavelet)
plt.show()
```

So how I can **rotate wavelet for example 90 degrees** shift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain a -90 degrees shift of a signal using the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform).
This provides a way to obtain other phase shifts via the [analytic representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Analytic_representation), implemented by [`scipy.signal.hilbert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html). Once you have this analytic signal, you 'simply' have to multiply by the complex phase term `exp(1j*np.radians(angle))`, and extract the real part:

```
N = 100
a = 10
x = np.arange(0,N)-0.5*(N-1)
wavelet = signal.ricker(N, a)

plt.plot(x,wavelet,label='wavelet')

angle = 90
shifted = np.real(np.exp(1j*np.radians(angle)) * signal.hilbert(wavelet))
plt.plot(x,shifted,label='90º shift')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much that is what I needed!

Comment: @Damir I have a follow-up query, let's say that I already got a ```x``` degree phase-shifted Ricker wavelet, how can I find this ```x``` degree phase shift from the wavelet?

Comment: @QuamerNasim it won't fit nicely in comments, but post it as a question & I answer it.